# Python Kivy/kivyMD load second screen method in authentication page

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I want to know the method of loading the second screen when authentication is passed.
I can call the second screen from the .kv file vi on_press or other methods. But I need to call from python code to check the authentication.
Can anyone help with my code?
Here is my code:

app.py

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


class my_layout(FloatLayout):
    screen_mngr = ObjectProperty(None)


class myapp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "BlueGray"
        return Builder.load_file("app.kv")

    def logger(self):
        if self.root.ids.user.text == 'admin' and self.root.ids.password.text=='admin':
            self.root.ids.welcome_label.text = f'Sup {self.root.ids.user.text}!'
            screen = Screen(name='screen2')
        else:
            self.root.ids.welcome_label.text = 'Wrong credentials'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    myapp().run()
```

And here is my design kv file.

app.kv file:

```
my_layout:
    
    screen_mngr: screen_mngr

    ScreenManager:
        id: screen_mngr
        home: home

        Screen:
            id: home
            name: 'home'

            MDCard:
                size_hint: None, None
                size: 450, 600
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
                elevation: 10
                padding: 25
                spacing: 25
                orientation: 'vertical'

                MDLabel:
                    id: welcome_label
                    text: "WELCOME"
                    font_size: 40
                    halign: 'center'
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: self.texture_size[1]
                    padding_y: 15


                MDTextField:
                    id: user
                    hint_text: "username"
                    icon_right: "account"
                    size_hint_x: None
                    width: 200
                    font_size: 18
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}

                MDTextField:
                    id: password
                    hint_text: "password"
                    icon_right: "eye-off"
                    size_hint_x: None
                    width: 200
                    font_size: 18
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}

                MDRoundFlatButton:
                    text: "LOG IN"
                    font_size: 12
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
                    on_press: screen2


        Screen:
            id: screen2
            name: 'screen2'

            MDRoundFlatButton:
                text: "This is Second Screen\nGo to Screen1"
                size_hint: 0.2,0.1
                pos_hint: {"center_x":0.5,"y":0.5}
                on_press: screen_mngr.current = "home"
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple small problems:

First, in your `kv` you need to have your `LOG IN` `Button` call the code to handle the log in, like this:

```
            MDRoundFlatButton:
                text: "LOG IN"
                font_size: 12
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
                on_press: app.logger()  # call the method that handles login
```

Then, in that method, you can change to the `screen2` by using the `current` property of the `ScreenManager`, like this:

```
def logger(self):
    if self.root.ids.user.text == 'admin' and self.root.ids.password.text=='admin':
        self.root.ids.welcome_label.text = f'Sup {self.root.ids.user.text}!'
        self.root.ids.screen_mngr.current = 'screen2'  # go to screen2
        # screen = Screen(name='screen2')
    else:
        self.root.ids.welcome_label.text = 'Wrong credentials'
```